# Put jQuery at the bottom of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's not the first time that I'm restyilin' my website and there's always this problem: when I analyze the page with the Google PageSpeed, it suggests me to put the Jquery and a few other .js codes at the bottom of the page to increase the loading speed.

The problem is that most of the time when I do that the slider, in this specific case, do not work.

Is there an easy solution for this?

I already minified and included the jquery on my wesbite as (jqu.js)

Comment: Try including all of your .js files at the bottom of the page. You can't separate the scripts if the rely on each other or need to be executed in a specific order.

Comment: Without seeing your code, or at least an error message, we can't really help you. You should be putting all your script tags just before the `</body>` tag though.

Comment: is your website in wordpress??

Comment: If your slider depends on jQuery, you need to put jQuery at the top because it is a dependency for the slider. Yes, putting JS at the bottom helps performance, but what's the point if it doesn't work... The other option is to make it so that your slider doesn't require jQuery to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always the case that jQuery can be loaded in the footer of the page. PageSpeed Insights does not catch the cases when this occurs, and thus will always give you a penalty. I'm familiar with this happening with various Carousel-type Javascript UI elements; it sounds like your slider is affected too.